# Are there any date limits for the Amazon MWS Orders API?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-mws

Anybody knows how far we can go back to query past (history) orders data?

For example: From current date to 1 year back or 2 year back or any limit.

Anyway to get the first date customer make an order?

Because I need to synchronize data between my own back-end and Amazon Seller Central Platform. Need to show progress of synchronization between my own back-end and Amazon Market Place Platform. Then end user knows how much history orders data pending for synchronization.

This for Amazon Seller Central Platform data analyzing & statistics report generation application.

Thank you,
Yohan

Comment: Hi Yohan I just used Amazon MWS scratchpad and using orders api i did  ListOrders requested using CreatedAfter parameter to 2008-01-01 and it gave me orders purchased in 2009, because we started dealing on amazon in 2009 so it's 8 years for me and also it gives you NextToken to get further orders as it only returns 100 orders per call.

Comment: @ Keyur Thank you very much for your quick reply. Using the solution you have propose I can build method to resolve my issue. Thank you very much again for your quick help.

Comment: You are welcome Yohan